# .send_keys method is not entering the expected data or else it is being ignored entirely

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have a situation where the driver.find_element(:id, “sometext” ).send_keys method is not entering the expected data or else it is being ignored entirely.

I am using Selenium WebDriver with Ruby and Windows 7.

Example:

In the code below the first two lines find the unit price field, clears it and then enters “100.00” in that field. In the second one the same behavior should enter “150.00” in the Broker Commission field but instead “0.1” gets entered instead and then the third one, which is the Shipping Fee field is completely ignored.

I have tried to do this using :id, :name and also :xpath with similar results. Note that there are other fields on the same page that enter the correct amounts using the same methods, but for these two I am unable to get it to work. Why would it vary for these two fields only?

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "frmfldUnitPrice2").clear
@driver.find_element(:id, "frmfldUnitPrice2").send_keys "100.00"
@driver.find_element(:id, "txtBrokerCommission").clear
@driver.find_element(:id, "txtBrokerCommission").send_keys "150"
@driver.find_element(:id, "txtShippingFee").clear
@driver.find_element(:id, "txtShippingFee").send_keys "100"
```

Comment: Would it be possible to create a sample page that would allow us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Possibly but I'll have to figure out a way.

Answer (score 0):

After much research I was able to figure out a solution. It is WAY simpler than I expected. Not elegant, but it works for this situation.

By entering a sendkeys command and backspace "\b" you solve the problem of the cursor going to the end of the default value. Since "clear" did not work I had to go to the field and then backspace 4 times to clear out 0.00 **("\b"*4)**

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "txtBrokerCommission").clear
@driver.find_element(:id, "txtBrokerCommission").send_keys ("\b"*4)
@driver.find_element(:id, "txtBrokerCommission").send_keys "150"
@driver.find_element(:id, "txtShippingFee").clear
@driver.find_element(:id, "txtShippingFee").send_keys ("\b"*4)
@driver.find_element(:id, "txtShippingFee").send_keys "100"
```